# Toggle the notification bar in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I know I can expand the notification bar by reflection

```
    Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
    Method showsb;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
    }
    else {
        showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
    }
    showsb.invoke( getSystemService( "statusbar" ) );
```

However, is there a way to expand it if it is collapsed, and collapse it if it is already expanded?

There is a toggle function for StatusBarManager in the android docs but it doesn't work for me.

EDITED

I am calling this function from inside a bound service.

Comment: Daniel, sorry that my (wrong) answer ended up taking the bounty here. I've been looking around and I haven't been able to find an answer to this anywhere online. I'll keep looking though!

Comment: There are no public API to do what you want. Even if you use reflection, it's still restricted- as you have found out.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you may be missing the needed permissions. Make sure that you have the EXPAND_STATUS_BAR permission in your Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Looking around, I found this code:

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
Method showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod( "expand" );
showsb.invoke( sbservice );
```

You may want to try it.

EDIT:

For actually detecting if it is down or not, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16297360/4015623). Here's what it looks like:

Override the onWindowFocusChanged() method in your activity with the code below:

In the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

The overriding:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    try
    {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
            Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
            Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
            Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
            collapse .setAccessible(true);
            collapse .invoke(service);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
            try {
                Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                collapse .setAccessible(true);
                collapse .invoke(service);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have the correct permissions and can expand the bar successfully.  However, I need a way to know if the bar is already expanded or not.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I am actually calling this function from a bound service.  So I could be viewing any app while this code is triggered. I've updated the original question, sorry about the missing details.

Comment: This is only applicable for your own app, but is it possible we can detect any statusbar expand at any time in the lifetime of the app? means can I implement these in the service kind of thing and we can implement these also on android lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work for new and old Android OS.

You need to enable the `EXPAND_STATUS_BAR` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
try {
    Object sbservice = getSystemService("statusbar");
    Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
    Method expandMethod;
    expandMethod = statusbarManager.getMethod(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17 ? "expandNotificationsPanel" : "expand");
    expandMethod.invoke(sbservice);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```